# One-way switch. Why is a separate pvc conduit used?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance

Why is it in the lighting circuit a separate earth wire is drawn in p.v.c conduit type of installation and not in steel type?

Comment: Not clear. Is it a separate PVC conduit or a separate earth wire you're talking about? Is your question about an existing installation, typical installations in a particular country, perhaps a guideline you were reading or something else entirely?

Comment: See also http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/74996/58292

Answer (score 5):

Because it's legal to use a continuous metallic conduit as the grounding conductor. If the conduit is not conductive, a wire must be pulled to act as the grounding conductor.