# issues wiring ceiling fan with remote and 2 switches

Tags: electrical, wiring, ceiling-fan

I've done some basic wiring but seem to be in over my head on figuring this one out. We have a solarium the had a ceiling light fixture and a switch at each end of the room. I removed the light and all there was is two wires feeding it. One white and one yellow. I hooked up the remote receiver by matching the colors on the fan side. That was easy because they match. On the feed side I hooked the white to white and then black to yellow. I have grounded the fixture to a screw in the outlet box. Firstly being a novice I was surprised the feed doesn't have a ground and also to see a yellow wire along with the white. Not sure where I'm going wrong but it definitely isn't working. I'll also add it's a challenge to stuff that remote box into the outlet box, barely fits. btw the fan is a Canarm "Perry" model 48 inch with remote. Thanks in advance ! 
Cheers,
Bruce[image: Existing wiring][image: fan wiring remote]

Comment: Is the junction box inside the ceiling **rated for a ceiling fan**?  If it is not, the box will need to be changed.  Normal boxes cannot cope with the vibration and weight of a ceiling fan.  Also this appears to be the *conduit wiring method* so your wire colors may be more whimsical.  That is a good thing, actually.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. The box is fine. Being a condo it's a large box actually poured into concrete so for sure it's not going anywhere. There is a conduit and for sure what threw me off was this whole 2-wire (yellow&white) and no ground. I suspect a little complicate by the fact there's 2 switches as well.  It's a really nice solarium but I really need to get this wiring figured out before the hot weather gets here. I also think the manufacturer should supply a shoe horn for the remote because it barely fits.

Comment: Legal neutral colors are white and gray.  Legal hot colors are all others but green.  So yellow is a fine hot color.  It's good to use for a circuit that is switched, since it's not the usual black, red or blue that you'd use for always-on circuits.

Comment: Thanks @Harper ! It's confusing. I was so sure I had wired it correctly and even tried the 2 switches in various positions in case one or the other was acting as the master but nothing. Sadly tonight after work I'll have to take is all apart or start to and try to see where the issue is. It looked straight forward enough. I'll take a couple pics tonight and share and maybe that'll help to see what's wrong. Every day is an education. Cheers

Comment: Maybe related to not having a ground: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/166099/43874.  And get a volt meter to check the voltage between that white and yellow so you have a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: If that's metal conduit, *that is the ground*.

Comment: ok, thanks JPhi1618 and @Harper. Seems I have a bit of work to do. Another one of those jobs that looked deceivingly simple when I started out.

Comment: On your diagram "pg#7" above, if you take the topmost word "black", cross it out and write "yellow", that should suffice.  By the way "outlet box" means your photo.  "outlet" literally means "any point of use", not just "receptacle" though a receptacle is a kind of outlet.

Comment: Can you post photos looking into the back of the box please?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Does this help? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wwvig.jpg

Comment: @Harper -- somewhat? I'm still a bit concerned about the adequacy of the box as a fan mounting means -- while I doubt the box will fall out of the ceiling, it may be that the screwears could bend and fail under fan loads?

Comment: Hello. Thanks everyone for the comments and feedback. Turns out after all that the issue was likely the way everything was stuffed in the box. I did have the wiring right but a couple things came up. When I started to pull everything out to check the feeder neutral marrette was a bit loose. Even tho I thought I had it secure I think jamming the remote unit in loosen it. I redid it, taped it and checked everything else was secure. That was the issue, a loose connection.Also figured out which 3 way is the power switch so all is good. Thx again everyone.

Comment: @BruceMcHendry -- post that as an answer and I'll give you a +1 for it